# ImportError: Module use of python26.dll conflicts with this version of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I use Python 3.2.3

Tonight I tried to install requests from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ by pip and easy_install, but it doesn't work. I have error when trying to import it. So I decided to use standard library urllib.request and see this error again

That is the traceback:

```
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "E:\Python32\lib\site-packages\requests-1.2.0-py3.2.egg\requests\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from . import utils
File "E:\Python32\lib\site-packages\requests-1.2.0-py3.2.egg\requests\utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    import cgi
File "E:\Python32\lib\cgi.py", line 38, in <module>
    from email.parser import FeedParser
File "E:\Python32\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser
File "E:\Python32\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
File "E:\Python32\lib\email\message.py", line 17, in <module>
    from email import utils
File "E:\Python32\lib\email\utils.py", line 28, in <module>
    import socket
File "E:\Python32\lib\socket.py", line 46, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: Module use of python26.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

So how can I fix this?

**UPD:** Solved. It was bug in SublimeREPL, reinstalled that package.

Comment: It looks to me like something is wrong with your python install.  You're python3.2 is trying to use the python26.dll rather than python32.dll as I would expect based on the common naming conventions ... What does your python path look like?  `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`

Comment: It looks like this:
C:\WINDOWS\system32\python32.zip
E:\Python32
E:\Python32\DLLs
E:\Python32\lib
E:\Python32\lib\site-packages
E:\Python32\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py3.2.egg
E:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pip-1.3.1-py3.2.egg
E:\Python32\lib\site-packages\requests-1.2.0-py3.2.egg
E:\Python32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py3.2.egg-info
E:\Python32\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp-1.1.11-py3.2.egg

Comment: @wiygn - If you solved the problem, can you post the solution as an "answer", so it is more visible.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I was using PythonXY. The Spyder was not loading and it turns out another software OpenCAD had installed Python2.6 version and that was not letting my Python27.dll to not work. After uninstalling OpenCAD, I was able to run the software.

I was able to troubleshoot by first searching for python26.dll and found that this file was located in the OpenCAD folder location and that made me realize that this software was causing the issue.